# Dataframe is Offset by -1 Days From Source Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dynamics-business-central

I am using a connector to query some tables in Dynamics 365 Business Central and when I view my dataframe all of my dates are offset by -1 days.

I generated a logfile for a specific invoice to use as an example, and in the logfile, I see the correct Posting_Date of "2022-04-01" and the query is completed successfully with the correct data that matches what I see in Business Cental.

Then, when I go to view the header, or load the dataframe to my PostgreSQL database, it shows as "2022-03-31." Anyone have any ideas on what might be going on here? Everything seems to look fine until I try to view my dataframe, where all records display the correct date -1.

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("d365businesscentral:///?InitiateOAuth=GETANDREFRESH;company=[company name];logfile=[logfile location];verbosity=3;timeout=0;OrganizationUrl=https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/[key]/[environment]/ODataV4")

df = pd.read_sql("""
    SELECT
    Posting_Date
    FROM Posted_Sales_Invoice_Lines
    where Document_No = 'PS-INV153588'
    ;""", engine)

print(df.head(5))
```

```
  Posting_Date
0   2022-03-31
1   2022-03-31
2   2022-03-31
3   2022-03-31
4   2022-03-31
[Finished in 8.805s]
```

Comment: is `Posting_Date` in DB Date type?  maybe timezone?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking maybe time zone might have something to do with it, but the field is in date, not in datetime format, and all the time zone settings I see are set to my local time zone PST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with PostgreSQL databases and dataframes.

However Business Central stores `DateTimes` in the database as UTC timestamps, which I guess could explain the offset, given that you are using PST as the timezone when reading the data.

Dates are also stored as `DateTime` but with the time set to `00:00:00`.